# Browse field data shows value, but displays another value

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have a formula written for a field in Crystal Reports. When i refresh the report, i get a different value from the formula. The required value is always the last value in Browse Field Data dialog for that formula. 
Isnt the formula supposed to have only one value as output? why are multiple values shown in browse field data dialog.? Is there a way to retrieve last value of Browse File Data dialog?

My formula looks like below:

```
WHILEREADINGRECORDS;
NumberVar CODTOTAL;
if {XXX.YYY} = 1 then
(    CODTOTAL := CODTOTAL  + {XXX.ZZZ};
);
CODTOTAL;
```

Browse field data shows all the values "CODTOTAL" acquires as a result of that formula and displays a random value amongst the assigned value.

Please help me out. I am amateur in crystal reports.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

~Regards.

Answer (score 0):

First observation should be where have you placed the formula (Details, Footer.. etc).

```
why are multiple values shown in browse field data dialog.?
```

Browse field shows the data that is present in the table but in your case you are applying "If" condition of the filed. It can be possible that there is only one record that satisfies your condition.

I would suggest to run the report without the codition, Check the results and apply the condition and check results again.